# Read huge tar.gz file stream-like way, line by line

Tags: bash, unix, tar

After some load tests I have a single 60 GB log file (the test stopped because this file used all disk space available). In order to be able to continue using the server, I had to tar-gzip this file, but now I would like to query this file without unpacking it as a whole. Is there a way to read this file line-by-line using tools available in linux command line?

Comment: Tar is not a comperssion format; tarring a single file, as such, accomplishes no savings -- you just add the `tar` headers around the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on CentOS 6

```
zcat file.tar.gz | tar -x -O -f -
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can simply open a .bz2 or .gz file in vim.

```
vim file.tar.bz2
```

And do your work there.

You can use bzcat or even bzgrep with .bz2, same as zcat or zgrep with .gz.

However, bzcat doesn't save much, as it actually also goes about and unpacks the file into stdout. So if you want to grep it, use zgrep or bzgrep.

It works nicely on huge files.

```
bzgrep "pattern" file.tar.bz2

bzcat file.tar.bz2
```

Tested on OSX 10.10

Comment: Of course, the `vim` method unpacks the entire file and stores it as a temporary file, with additional metadata that will make it larger than the original file was. This may not be advisable in the current circumstance...